# Generate QR Code from Vcard ZXING Android

Tags: android, qr-code, zxing

I'm Creating a Android qr code generator app using ZXING QRGen.Now i want to embed Contact info to qrcode and save it in to my phone internal memory as a png image.this is from GitHub ZXING sample i tryed.

```
VCard johnDoe = new VCard("abc Doe")
                .setEmail("abc.doe@example.org")
                .setAddress("John Doe Street 1, 5678 Doestown")
                .setTitle("Mister")
                .setCompany("John Doe Inc.")
                .setPhoneNumber("1234")
                .setWebsite("www.example.org");


       File file= QRCode.from(johnDoe).file();
        Log.d("exc", file.toString());
```

this Log display `/data/data/qr.abc.xx.QR/cache/QRCode-406605015.png` i want to save qr .png file into my internal memory

Comment: Mean you want to create QR code for those contacts which are stored in your mobile?

Comment: Yes,i want to create QR code and save tha image in internal memory

Comment: By following this example, you can create your own QRCode. For accessing the contacts from your phone use ContentProvider.

Comment: yes i want to save this image in my phone memory

Comment: That is what I am telling use `ContentProvider` to access the contacts from your phone and create your own image and store it.

Comment: Which part you are not understanding?

Comment: Hello! Are you there?